# Heroku Postgres: relation does not exist

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I've created a Java Spring website through TDD. Initially, it only needed the embedded h2 database that spring boot comes with. I eventually realized that since I'm hosting on Heroku which does not support h2 I would have to make a switch so I went with postgres. Since I've added postgres as a dependency and switched to using Heroku's environment variable for a datasource my website has failed to start. The tricky part is all my tests pass still since I'm still testing with h2 and only using postgres on production. This is the stacktrace that I see in Heroku's logs when I deploy the website.

```
State changed from starting to up
2018-06-22 18:28:08.543  INFO 4 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 58859 (http)
2018-06-22 18:28:09.341  WARN 4 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
2018-06-22 18:28:09.368 ERROR 4 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "category" does not exist Position: 13
2018-06-22 18:28:09.502  INFO 4 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-06-22 18:28:09.599 ERROR 4 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:735) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:716) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:703) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.wecancodeit.pantryplus.PantryplusApplication.main(PantryplusApplication.java:10) [classes!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [pantryplus-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [pantryplus-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [pantryplus-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [pantryplus-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:503) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:209) ~[spring-tx-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.10.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.wecancodeit.pantryplus.ProductPopulator.run(ProductPopulator.java:26) ~[classes!/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:732) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2855) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3426) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:619) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:273) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:254) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:299) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:272) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:775) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:748) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:753) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1146) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:508) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.10.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:513) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:498) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:475) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "category" does not exist Position: 13
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2455) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2155) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:288) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:430) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:356) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:168) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:135) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar!/:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.executeUpdate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 68 common frames omitted

2018-06-22 18:28:09.612  INFO 4 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5cb0d902: startup date [Fri Jun 22 18:27:14 UTC 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-06-22 18:28:09.663  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2018-06-22 18:28:09.690  INFO 4 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
State changed from up to crashed
Process exited with status 1
```

Sorry about the timestamps by the way, if anyone knows a service that formats stacktrace's feel free to share in the comments.
The beginning of the stacktrace says `ERROR: relation "category" does not exist` which makes me believe it has something to do with my `Product.java` and `Category.java` classes as they have a `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")` relationship.

Category.java

```
package org.wecancodeit.pantryplus.category;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import org.wecancodeit.pantryplus.product.Product;

@Entity
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    private Collection<Product> products;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Category() {
    }

    public Category(String name, Product... products) {
        this.name = name;
        this.products = new HashSet<Product>(asList(products));
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Collection<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }
}
```

Product.java

```
package org.wecancodeit.pantryplus.product;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import org.wecancodeit.pantryplus.category.Category;
import org.wecancodeit.pantryplus.lineitem.LineItem;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String image;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    private Category category;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    private Collection<LineItem> lineItem;

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(String name, Category category) {
        this.name = name;
        this.category = category;
    }

    public Product(String name, Category category, String image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.category = category;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return ((Long) id).hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        if (id == ((Product) obj).id) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

}
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.10.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'net.saliman.cobertura' version '2.3.1'
    id 'com.github.kt3k.coveralls' version '2.8.2'
    id 'com.craigburke.karma' version '1.4.4'
}

cobertura.coverageFormats = ['html', 'xml']

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

karma {
    frameworks = ['jasmine']
    browsers = [
        'Chrome'
    ]
    files = [
        "src/test/js/*spec.js",
        "src/main/resources/static/js/*.js"
    ]
}

group = 'org.wecancodeit'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

test {
    environment "JDBC_DATABASE_URL", "" //I don't know how this empty quote is working but it works just as well as 'jdbc:h2:~/test' for some reason
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail')
    compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-hal-browser')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')
    testCompile('com.h2database:h2')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

I've been stuck at this for a couple weeks now, I've even been able to build websites after this from the ground up that worked with postgres on Heroku but not this one. I wouldn't be surprised if this was an issue with whitespace.

Edit:
Here's my application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=${SPRING_MAIL_USERNAME}
spring.mail.password=${SPRING_MAIL_PASSWORD}
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
```

Edit 2:
I've hit my character limit so I can't add the full Heroku logs but I've uploaded them to google drive at: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1668kZuNsDWuiVQMvP4waFBs_sU9xvrWO/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my table names was `user`, this is a Postgres keyword and after I changed this and completely rewrote this project in Spring Boot 2 I was able to get this working. Here's a list of postgres keywords: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you properly configured schema in your properties file ?
According to heroku docs:

> Notice the additional ql at the end of jdbc:postgresql? Due to this difference you will need to hardcode the scheme to jdbc:postgresql in your Java class or your Spring XML configuration.([link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-java))

Comment: I've previously taken this article's advice when I wrote `spring.datasource.url=${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}` in the `application.properties`